# save visual stimuli created by psychtoolbox into video files

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

Does anyone knows how to capture the screen while running an experiment using Matlab psychtoolbox, to save it as a film which I can upload later to the web?

Answer (score 1):

See `Screen('CreateMovie?')`, example usage is provided in `ImagingStereoDemo`. Make sure you have an up-to-date psychtoolbox installation (run `UpdatePsychtoolbox`) and the latest recommended GStreamer version to have the highest chance of success with this.

Comment: Thanks! The problem with Screen('CreateMovie') is that you have to have some loop in your program, to save the movie frame by frame using AddFrameToMovie.